# in mod_rewrite how can I write a rule that redirect everything except everything for a specific directory?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

On my Apache server I have this rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule (.*) /shindig/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This redirects every request to /shindig/index.php,
I want to redirect every request except those for anything in this path: /myOrigPath

How can I do this? Please assume that I have almost no knowledge of mod_rewrite

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another `RewriteCond` and exclude that path:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myOrigPath
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /shindig/index.php [L]
```

You could also check the matched value of your `RewriteRule` pattern instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}` with either `$0` (whole match) or `$1` (match of the first group).